# How do I take a loss on an IRA I converted to a Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, ira, losses

Can I take a loss on conversion? If so, how do I do so (i.e. what U.S. tax form do I use)?

Answer (score 3):

The rules are complex. See [How to Deduct IRA Losses](http://www.smartmoney.com/personal-finance/taxes/how-to-deduct-ira-losses/), at Smart Money. 
You must liquidate the entire account (bad) and the loss is subject to the amount exceeding 2% of your AGI. If you are subject to AMT, you may lose any or all of that remaining amount.